# Using jQuery, if we append a script element, why is the file's URL added with ?_=timestamp?

Tags: jquery

Let's say if we go to any website that has jQuery (such as http://www.jquery.com), and then in the debug console, we use

```
jQuery("body").append("<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>");
```

In both Chrome or Firefox, I see in the Network tab it pulled in the file:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js?_=1366193092174
```

So looks like it is pulling in the file with a UNIX timestamp added to the end.  I tried pulling in a can.js file:

```
jQuery("body").append("<script src='http://canjs.com/release/latest/can.jquery.js'></script>");
```

and it was the same, so it shouldn't be a server thing (I used Charles Proxy to check and it didn't seem like there was a HTTP redirect at first).

I then used 2 blank pages, one is using jQuery developer version and the other using the `.min` production version, to see if the production version won't add the `?_=1366193092174` part, but they both did add it.  jQuery's append() doc didn't mention any timestamp or `_=` either on the page.  What actually is happening and what if for some reason, I don't want the part `?_=1366193092174` added, is there a way?

Comment: I think it is used to force browsers to load non cached pages...

Comment: I guess this Timestamp is added to prevent the file to be loaded from the cache.
Maybe you should prefer load dynamically a script $.ajax directly, instead of appending a script tag ?
This way you could set the cache option to true or false.

Watch this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537032/how-do-i-stop-jquery-appending-a-unique-id-to-scripts-called-via-ajax

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp is added at end of url because jQuery sets `cache: false` for `script` calls which appends the timestamp to the URL. Instead of `append()`, you could use:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js",
  dataType: "script",
  cache: true,
  success: function(){
    // ....
  }
});
```

Comment: That's interesting... it works every time, so is this a more preferred way to add a script file to the page?  I thought the line `jQuery("body").append("<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>");` is very close to the old method of `document.createElement` and setting the `src` to point to the script file, so looks like jQuery will see that it is a script tag and then "short circuit" the operation by doing `$.ajax`?

Comment: by the way, looks like a good way is `$.getScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js")` as in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: yea, jQuery does special-handle script tags when doing DOM manipulations. It filters them out and requests them via ajax, so using $.ajax({..}); with cache set to true should be a proper workaround..

Comment: By default, $.getScript() sets the cache setting to false. This appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested. Check in the same url you posted

Comment: by the way, isn't adding it to the DOM makes it the most "browser way of handling it", inside of loading the content by AJAX and then evaluating the script?  What if the implementation logic has some flaw, and if so, the browser's way (of adding a DOM element of the `<script>` tag) should be the most raw and reliable mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is cache problem as browser when call to script link it see that there are new parameter to send  to this url , so to prevent calling each time to this script you need  remove this problem and till the browser to cache your script after first time :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // Enable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: true
});
```

Comment: it works... and it works once... so if I use `jQuery("body").append("<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>");` a second time, then it would pull using `cache: false` again

Comment: it works once in your example because you load and execute the whole jQuery source again. It overwrites all your ajaxSetup configuration to its default values