# Force cache static resources while page partially updating

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, browser, browser-cache

I know how browser caches resources. This scenario I am getting is different than usual.

I have this single page application coded in `asp.net mvc` framework. At the first load every static resources like `js`, `css`,`images` are getting cached properly. This application will append fresh html into the main page when navigating, with some js files too.

When I inspected in the chrome network tab I found the problem as, with each files which comes after the first load, the browser appending a number each time with the file name(looks like a versioning technique) and this prevent it from caching, making the app too slow.  I do not have any idea or settings exists to disable this in mvc

Also I found this strange that the `js` files which comes after the first load are categorised under `xhr` requests in chrome network tab

How to force cache these files?

[image: Network details]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with jquery version. Jquery was the culprit who add this unique number to every `js` file injected to the DOM using it's APIs such as `append` and `html`. Updating jquery fixed this issue

[How do I stop jquery appending a unique id to scripts called via ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537032/how-do-i-stop-jquery-appending-a-unique-id-to-scripts-called-via-ajax)